# Андроид 4 статистика

Tags: android

Стоит ли сейчас включать в приложения поддержку приложения версии Андроид ниже 5-ой? По-моему через несколько лет устройств с Андроид ниже 5ой версии станет гораздо меньше? Как вы считаете?

Comment: Что будет через несколько лет, будет только через несколько лет, как странно это бы не звучало:). Сейчас же лично я делаю проекты под 4.2/4.4 +. Поддержка 4.x версий лишним не будет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У гугла есть страничка с информацией, постоянно обновляемой, по доли девайсов с разными уровнями версий ОС:

https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

По состоянию на сейчас, май 2017:

- 95% устройств - 4.2+
- 70% устройств - 5+

Сам гугл рекомендует поддерживать 95% устройств, как это можно увидеть при создании нового проекта в студии.

Как бы не хотелось не поддерживать версии ниже 5, в данный момент игнорирование 25% юзеров с ОС 4.2-4.4.4 - может чувствительно повлиять на доступную аудиторию приложения.

Comment: Поняла, спасибо